# curly curly operator doesnt work with map() in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, curly-braces

```
library(tidyverse)
mean_by <- function(data,by,conti){
  
  data %>% group_by({{by}}) %>% summarise(mean=mean({{conti}})) %>% 
    print() %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x={{by}},y=mean))+geom_col()
}

map(mtcars %>% select_if(is.numeric),~mean_by(mtcars,cyl,.))
# Not quite the same 
mean_by(mtcars,cyl,carb)
```

I was toying around with the curly curly operator in R (just learned about it!) and then when iterating using map it seemd like the grouping isnt working very well, and I cant get my hands around the problem. What am I doing wrong?

Btw, When trying the explicit pmap way, I couldnt get around using the cyl variable in a clever way

```
pmap(mtcars %>% select_if(is.numeric),mean_by,..1=mtcars,..2=cyl,..3=.)
```

Error in `pmap()`:
i In index: 1.
Caused by error in `withCallingHandlers()`:
! object 'cyl' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

> 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expecting the column names and not the values - here, the `select_if` returns a subset of columns that are numeric.  We may need the `names` to loop which would be a string, thus it is better to convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
mean_by <- function(data,by,conti){
  by_sym <- rlang::ensym(by)
  conti <- rlang::ensym(conti)
  
  data %>% group_by(!! by_sym) %>% 
   summarise(mean=mean(!!conti)) %>% 
    print() %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x= !!by_sym,y=mean))+geom_col()
}

map(mtcars %>% 
    select_if(is.numeric) %>%
    names,~mean_by(mtcars,cyl, !!.x))
```

-output (graphs removed)

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
    cyl  mean
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4  26.7
2     6  19.7
3     8  15.1
# A tibble: 3 × 2
    cyl  mean
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4     4
2     6     6
3     8     8
# A tibble: 3 × 2
    cyl  mean
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4  105.
2     6  183.
3     8  353.
# A tibble: 3 × 2
    cyl  mean
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4  82.6
2     6 122. 
3     8 209. 
# A tibble: 3 × 2
    cyl  mean
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4  4.07
2     6  3.59
3     8  3.23
# A tibble: 3 × 2
    cyl  mean
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4  2.29
2     6  3.12
3     8  4.00
# A tibble: 3 × 2
    cyl  mean
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4  19.1
2     6  18.0
3     8  16.8
# A tibble: 3 × 2
    cyl  mean
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4 0.909
2     6 0.571
3     8 0    
# A tibble: 3 × 2
    cyl  mean
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4 0.727
2     6 0.429
3     8 0.143
# A tibble: 3 × 2
    cyl  mean
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4  4.09
2     6  3.86
3     8  3.29
# A tibble: 3 × 2
    cyl  mean
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4  1.55
2     6  3.43
3     8  3.5
```

Comment: Thanks! It does work and it is slight more elegant than my version without the curly curly. I did hope to use the curly curly operator since it seemed so nice but I thank you for the time and explanation. If anyone interested, a different and yet working approach in the next commet

Comment: mean_byt <- function(data,by,conti){
  data %>% group_by(.data[[by]]) %>% summarise(mean=mean(.data[[conti]])) %>% 
    print() %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=.data[[by]],y=mean))+geom_col()
}
map(colnames(select_if(mtcars,is.numeric)),~mean_byt(mtcars,"cyl",.x))

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen the tilde syntax with `map`, but if you change that it seems to work.

```
map(mtcars %>% select_if(is.numeric), mean_by, data=mtcars, by=cyl)
```

Side note, you don't need that `print()` statement in `mean_by`.

```
mean_by <- function(data,by,conti){
  data %>% group_by({{by}}) %>% summarise(mean=mean({{conti}})) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x={{by}},y=mean))+geom_col()
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The output is the same and still did not group the continuous variable. I think the next answer will help us both